# How SQL/sqlite wildcars work? LIKE operator

Tags: sql, sqlite, wildcard, sql-like

How wildcards in `sqlite` work. Or how `LIKE` operator matches.
For examle lets say:

1: `LIKE('s%s%', 's12s12')`
    2: `LIKE('asdaska', '%sk%')`

In 1st example what % matches after 1st **s**, and how it decides to continue matching % or **s** after **%**.
In 2nd example if s matches first then **FALSE** returned.
Both examples return **TRUE**. From my Programming knowledge I came up with that LIKE function is some like a recursive function that when 2 possibilities appear function calls itself with 2 different params and uses **OR** between them, then obviously if one call returns true, upper function directly returns true.  If it is so, then LIKE operator is quiet slow to use on large  DBs.
P.S. There is one more **'_'** wildcard which matches exactly one character
I couldnt find any detailed documentation of LIKE operator.

Answer (score 2):

`%` matches zero or more characters, `_` matches exactly one.

Your first pattern `'s%s%'` would match, `'ss'`, `'s1s'`, `'s1111s'`, `'ss1111'`, etc. etc.

However if you wrote `'s_s_'` it would match `'s1s1'`, but none of the above.

Comment: I know that it does, but how **LIKE** function behave, how function decide to match or not each char?

Comment: I mean, how it decides whether to match reg. expression to current char or next expression to the char

Comment: Unfortunately to know the details you'd have to have access to the source. However it will probably work like any regex pattern matcher.